# How to pass pointer-to-pointer to NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval with ARC

Tags: objective-c, pointers, automatic-ref-counting

I'm trying to pass an indirect pointer to NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats: as follows:

```
-(void)assignResultAfterDelay:(Result **)resultPtr {
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1000 
                                    target:self
                                  selector:@(assignResult:)
                                  userInfo:resultPtr  // how to do this?
                                   repeats:NO];
 }
```

This doesn't work because of the cast from (Result * __strong *) to id, which gives an "Implicit conversion of an indirect pointer to an Objective-C pointer to 'id'" error.

Variations and combinations of bridged casts such as `(__bridge id)resultPtr`, using `objc_unretainedPointer(resultPtr)`, or changing the pointer type to `(Result * __weak *)` have not helped.  What is the right way to do this?

I suppose I could create a wrapper class that holds my indirect pointer and send an instance of that, but that seems ugly.  Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out.  NSInvocation lets me compile:

```
-(void)assignResultAfterDelay:(Result * __strong *)resultPtr {
    NSMethodSignature *sig = [self methodSignatureForSelector:@selector(assignResult:)];
    NSInvocation *inv = [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:sig];
    [invocation setTarget:self];
    [invocation setSelector:@selector(assignResult:)];
    [invocation setArgument:resultPtr atIndex:0];

    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1000 invocation:inv repeats:NO];
}

// where assign result looks like:
-(void)assignResult:(Result * __strong *)resultPtr { ... }
```